# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. Request was aborted c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a small windows application that uses a client certificate to make an HttpWebRequest.The client requires that I include an X509Certificate(.cer file self signed certificate) in the request. But iam getting the following error "The request was aborted.Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."  I even tried with .pfx file but getting the same error. And below is the code for the same:

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
                delegate (Object obj, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors)
                {
                    // trust any certificate
                    return true;
                };
                ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;

```
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            string certPath1 = @"C:\tmpVenDXCCert.cer";

            X509Certificate xc = new X509Certificate(certPath1, "vendor@123");           

            HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)
            WebRequest.Create("https://the-payments-place.com:8449");
            Request.ClientCertificates.Add(xc);
            Request.UserAgent = "Client Cert Sample";
            Request.Method = "GET";
            HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
```

Any help would be appreciated highly.

Regards,

Ram

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

1. Install the certificate in LocalMachine Store using "mmc.exe". Refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb950259(v=bts.10).aspx
2. Use following code

X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My,

```
  StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

      store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly); 

      X509Certificate2Collection collection = store.Certificates;

      X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = collection.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, certificateName,false);

     var certificate = new X509Certificate2();

      certificate = certCollection[0];

      webRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
```

3. Replace certificatename with your cert's subject name.